# Appending Text to a Field within an IF Statement (JSON)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, error, json-formatting

I am trying to append text to a field within an IF statement (intent shown in 3).

I understand how to append the basic text (shown in 1).

I understand how to set up the IF statement (shown in 2).

However I am unsure of how to combine these into 3. The code shown is my best guess, but returns an error. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Try solution given in my answer below. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, that worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped you! Keep using this platform for asking question related to SharePoint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use expression like below:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$Progress] == '', 'Required' , [$Progress]*100 + '%')"
```

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)